# Why I am getting this line in green colour in Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41d2b6d8 time:1933928?

Tags: android

Since I have updated my phone version from 4.3 to 4.4.4 it started showing this line and it annoying me very much
***"Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41d2b6d8 time:1933928"***

Please help how to solve his problem and why I am getting this error.

Comment: I had the same issue. It was because the code was using different objects of `context`. In my app, I am using a `View` (instead of `Activity` for some specific reasons, but it behaves the same I believe). I was adding the `View` in `WindowManager` in two scenarios. In one scenario, I was using `Application`'s `context` and in other scenario I was using the `BroadcastReceiver`'s `context`. I replaced the second one with `Application`'s `context` and now its working fine. I hope this helps.

Comment: got any solutions?